# How to fetch count of unique IDs number from firebase realtime database.Is there any query for this?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to fetch count of unique IDs number from firebase realtime database.Is there any query for this?"Do I have to fetch all data for getting count of data?

Comment: Do you mean unique id for the node on which you are going to save data right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase queries currently don't have a way to return only the number of nodes. The only way is to pull down the nodes and count them or create a child counter that you can increment each time you create a sub node.